# Bits not flipping

Tags: python

I wanted to create a program that does the `|` job. The program has zero errors but for some reason the first three bits don't want to flip but the rest works perfectly.

I've poured over my code and have fixed lots of issues but this one's just escaping me. I feel as if its obvious but it looks like it should work.

I plug in

```
print(bitor(11101010100101, 10111010))
print(bin(0b11101010100101 | 0b10111010))
```

and the results I get are:

```
0b11101010111010
0b11101010111111
```

I'm comparing it to pythons built in or function for bits and its just the first three.
Here's where I believe the problem is:

```
def bitor(x, y):
    bit1 = list(str(x))
    bit2 = list(str(y))
    lenchk = False
    result = []
    count = 0
    l1 = len(bit1) - 1
    l2 = len(bit2) - 1
    # checks to see which bit is longer so later on when we cant compare bits anymore it
    # switches over to the longer bit
    if l1 > l2:
        lenchk = True
    elif l1 < l2:
        lenchk = False
    # here we use our check to see the longer bit then we compare bits at their last index
    # working our way down appending 0's and 1's depending on if either are 1's or if both are 0's
    if lenchk:
        for _ in bit2:
            print(bit1[l1], bit2[l2])
            if bit1[l1] and bit2[l2] == "0":
                result.append("0")
                l2 -= 1
                l1 -= 1
                count += 1
            elif bit1[l1] or bit2[l2] == "1":
                result.append("1")
                l2 -= 1
                l1 -= 1
                count += 1
            elif count >= len(bit2):
                break
        # once the smaller bit reaches index 0 we continue on with the longer one
        while l1 >= 0:
            if bit1[l1] == "1":
                result.append("1")
                l1 -= 1
            elif bit1[l1] == "0":
                result.append("0")
                l1 -= 1
    # does the same thing as above code but if the second bit is longer
    elif lenchk is False:
        for _ in bit1:
            if bit2[l2] and bit1[l1] == "0":
                result.append("0")
                l2 -= 1
                l1 -= 1
                count += 1
            elif bit2[l2] or bit1[l1] == "1":
                result.append("1")
                l2 -= 1
                l1 -= 1
                count += 1
            elif count >= len(bit1):
                break
        while l2 >= 0:
            if bit2[l2] == "1":
                result.append("1")
                l2 -= 1
            elif bit2[l2] == "0":
                result.append("0")
                l2 -= 1
    # we reverse the bit to get the actual desired result and convert out list into a string
    result.reverse()
    result = ''.join(map(str, result))
    return "0b" + result
```

Comment: `if bit1[l1] and bit2[l2] == "0"` is not doing what you think.

Comment: `if bit1[l1] and bit2[l2] == "0":` should be `if bit1[l1] == bit2[l2] == "0":`

Comment: `elif bit1[l1] or bit2[l2] == "1":` should be `elif bit1[l1] == "1" or bit2[l2] == "1":

Answer (score 0):

I had to change if bit1[l1] and bit2[l2] == "0": to if bit1[l1] == bit2[l2] == "0":

thanks to barmar and trincot.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` conditions are not correct. For instance:

```
if bit1[l1] and bit2[l2] == "0"
```

Really means:

```
if (bit1[l1])   and    (bit2[l2] == "0")
```

Since the left operand of the `and` operator is truthy (since it is a string that is not empty), the condition will always be true.

You can however simplify the logic a lot when you realise that the result bit should be `max(bit1[l1], bit2[l2])`. This covers all cases.

Using some other techniques, like using `zip()` to combine corresponding bits, and reversing the input so that corresponding bits are at the *same* index, you can reduce the code to this:

```
def bitor(x, y):
    x = str(x)[::-1]
    y = str(y)[::-1]
    result = "".join(map(max, zip(x, y))) + x[len(y):] + y[len(x):]
    return "0b" + result[::-1]
```

---

Unrelated, but it is rather strange that you re-interpret a number's digits in decimal notation as *binary* digits. This can be quite confusing.